# C program not compiled properly on Objective-C Compiler

Tags: c, objective-c, pointers, int, scanf

I'm relatively new to Objective-C
I know its a superset of C. But when I try to compile this C code in GCC it gives me an error and Im not able to execute the code.

```
  #include <stdio.h>  
  int main(){  
   int x;
   printf("Input int:\n");
   scanf("%d", x);
   printf("%d", x);
    return 0;             
}
```

And when I do this other code, there is no error, but the output is wrong.
Note: The only change is "int *x".

```
   #include <stdio.h>  
   int main(){  
   int *x;
   printf("Input int:\n");
   scanf("%d", x);
   printf("%d", x);
    return 0;             
}

  INPUT: 3
  OUTPUT: 2147307520
```

Comment: They're both wrong in both languages.

Answer (score 9):

You need to allocate space for the integer as in the first, but you need to pass a pointer to `scanf()` as in the second — sort of; you need to pass the address of the integer to `scanf()`.  You should write:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(void)
{  
    int x;
    printf("Input int:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;             
}
```

This is now working C code; the chances are it will work as Objective C as well.  It is a good idea to include a newline at the end of printed output, too.